# Getting [Object Promise] while trying to return data using Axios in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, es6-promise, web-development-server

I am trying to write code to display value of bitcoin in USD, it works fine in console log but when I try to return it to my app.post, it just returns [Object Promise] on screen, I tried the same without using Async and Await and I get the same error, but in console it says Promise Pending

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { res } = require("express");
const axios=require("axios");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
})

async function getUser(fiat) {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/"+fiat+".json")
          let data = response.data.bpi.USD.rate;
              console.log(data);
              return data;
          
        }
         catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
  
app.post("/",function(req,res){
    var fiat = req.body.fiat;
    let answer=getUser(fiat);
    res.write(" "+answer);
    res.send();
    res.end();
});

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Server Started");
})
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You neeed await before  calling getUser also make this function async

```
 let answer=await getUser(fiat);
```

Comment: Adding await in the answer declaration line throws another error saying "await is only valid in async function"

Comment: Yes because i told you add async in the function

Comment: async function getUser(fiat)

Is this wrong syntax?